# using regex in p4 filelog?

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to use regex in perforce commands like "p4 filelog"?
I am trying to get information on file but not sure which perforce branch the file exists in. For example, //something/*/something/test.pl

Comment: Yes, absolutely you can do that. Did you try it? It works fine for me, although be careful because it may return a LOT of data!

Comment: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/manuals/cmdref/filespecs.html